# Openpyxl : iter_rows/ iter_cols Type Error

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to access an entire row or a column using the `iter_rows` and `iter_cols` and then do some operations such as adding colour, font etc. Now when I access the row or column using the method I am getting the following error

`TypeError: iter_rows() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_row'`

Here is the code that I am using

```
for rows in ws.iter_rows(min_row = 1, max_row = 1, min_col = 1):
            for cell in rows:
                cell.fill = PatternFill(bgColor="87ceeb", fill_type = "solid")

for cols in ws.iter_cols(min_col = 1, max_col = 1, min_row = 1):
            for cell in cols:
                cell.fill = PatternFill(bgColor="87ceeb", fill_type = "solid")`
```

Comment: `iter_rows(range_string=’‘, row_offset=0, column_offset=0)`

Comment: Update the version of openpyxl you're using.

Comment: @ryugie okay so how do I select only the first row or the column without knowing the range?

Comment: @Zedak - I'd just update openpyxl like Charlie said which would have those parameters min_row etc.

Comment: Yeah I updated my openpyxl version. It works now.

Comment: See https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html#a1-2016-04-11

Answer (score 0):

Resolved in comments:

> The OP updated his openpyxl version. It works now.